# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on device 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using cordova/ionic, but since the iOS 9 update i'm unable to deploy to a device. My app works on an emulator but i keep getting the same error when i deploy to a device whatever i try. I am aware that there are a ton of posts concerning this problem, but none have been able to solve my problem.

Is there anybody who experiences the same problem using the same platform (ionic/cordova).

This is how my .plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>io.cordova.myappff160c</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.6</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.6</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>m.facebook.com</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>graph.facebook.com</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>api.facebook.com</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Birdy.life</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>fb1074874362552202</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
      <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

And this is the output that i am getting when deploying to a device:

```
2016-05-30 17:31:53.465 Birdy[1102:584334] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.1 is starting.

2016-05-30 17:31:53.468 Birdy[1102:584334] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES

2016-05-30 17:31:53.576 Birdy[1102:584334] Using UIWebView

2016-05-30 17:31:53.581 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.264049ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.588 Birdy[1102:584334] Unlimited access to network resources

2016-05-30 17:31:53.590 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 7.857978ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.591 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.279963ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.592 Birdy[1102:584334] Starting Facebook Connect plugin

2016-05-30 17:31:53.593 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][facebookconnectplugin] 1.308978ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.626 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 32.754004ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.663 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][localstorage] 35.548985ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.664 Birdy[1102:584334] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 84.178030ms

2016-05-30 17:31:53.973 Birdy[1102:584334] Resetting plugins due to page load.

2016-05-30 17:31:55.337 Birdy[1102:584398] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

2016-05-30 17:31:55.340 Birdy[1102:584398] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

2016-05-30 17:31:55.448 Birdy[1102:584398] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

2016-05-30 17:31:55.711 Birdy[1102:584334] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/F5E4D8B5-7A45-4DA7-B7CE-CFC12DB7A5FF/Birdy.app/www/index.html#/public/home

2016-05-30 17:31:56.066 Birdy[1102:584392] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

2016-05-30 17:31:56.126 Birdy[1102:584392] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

2016-05-30 17:31:58.309 Birdy[1102:584398] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

The only thing i see is the splashscreen, and that's about it. Am i missing something or looking past it?

Comment: Are you using https by any chance? Seems like certificate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try just this for your `NSAppTransportSecurity` `Info.plist` setting.  The error you are getting indicates that your server is not using the latest and greatest TLS or is somehow misconfigured in another manner.  I believe when you start to specify more than what I have below you actually restrict things rather than making them wide open (which I assume is what you want).

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Request you to go through the question once again as the attributes you mentioned are already defined.

Comment: I'm suggesting you take out the other values in the 'NSAppTransportSecurity' dict.

Comment: I guess those values are added for some restricted access by the user, Not sure though.

Comment: They are specific exceptions, but he specified a global exception higher up, so they aren't useful to his purpose.

Comment: But dont you feel is it related to some certificate issue as the error says it is SSL related?

Comment: It is probably related to the TLS configuration of the server causing App Transport Security to reject the connection, but it looks like the intent is to bypass App Transport Security entirely.

Comment: Got it Charles. Thanks for your time. Gud day Hope this conversation helps the user too.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with an Ionic 4 app.  I'm trying to deploy to an actual device via xCode but I'm getting:
Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

I searched VSCODE for NSAppTransportSecurity but couldn't find it.  Where does this change have to be made?

Comment: @D.Hodges I'm not familiar with VSCODE, but you would need to add the content in my answer to the Info.plist.  It does not exist initially, so searching for NSAppTransportSecurity wouldn't do you much good.  The Info.plist always stores things like the bundle ID, bundle name, and bundle version for your app though.  Perhaps searching for the key for one of those (like CFBundleIdentifier) would be more useful.